# Delphi linux firemonkey GUI

Tags: delphi

I am going to buy Delphi Tokyo because my company has XE2 and we need a fresh update. I see that Delphi tokyo has Linux support but I have 2 questions:

1) I have seen that I can make apps for linux ubuntu server. Does Delphi allow apps for ubuntu client lts as well?

2) Can delphi produce GUI? I mean firemonkey support for linux so that I can use buttons and so on. If not is it planned?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Offtopic, but 1: yes, 2: http://fmxlinux.com/

Comment: Surely this is a question for the vendor .....

Answer (score 5):

Currently, there isn't any native support for Linux client applications - however, third party client support is available via [FmxLinux](https://www.fmxlinux.com/).

Comment: This product is not available. I think the question should be closed. You could have better mentioned that product in a comment.

Comment: This product was, and still is available: https://www.fmxlinux.com/

Comment: It wasn't when I wrote that comment, over four years ago

Comment: Your comments are confusing to me... not sure where I would have invented a link to the product back in 2017.  1.0 was released shortly before I posted that answer.  It was beta tested quite a while before 1.0 was released.  One example from 2017: https://flixengineering.com/archives/446

Comment: I didn't say that you invented the link. I just pointed out that at the time you answered the product was pre release and not available. Obviously I wouldn't have made that up, as I'm sure you appreciate.

Comment: Last response.  I posted a historical link to Flix...they reviewed the product on April 17, 2017.  It was available for use.  They were on version 0.99 something trying to get final release with a target of May 1, but also trying to get people to use it which is why I posted the answer.  Enough brain cycles wasted on this...

Comment: I'm confident that I didn't make anything up so the only explanation that makes sense is that the product was pre release at the time of this answer. As a recommendation question, that has been closed as such, the answer should not even have been posted.